# Can't lengthen size of Bootstrap 3's form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the documents(http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) it states you can control the column sizing with the .col-lg-* classes. However, changing that on my form only changes where the form is placed, not the actual size of it. I want the form to be a lot longer than what it is now, but can't seem to change the size.

My code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 align="center">Search</h1>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
             <form align="center" class="form-control" action="/search/" method ="get" role="form">
           <input id="navPersonSearch" type="text" name="q"
            placeholder="Search for Person"
            autocomplete="off" >
      </form> 
      </div> <!-- /.col -->
    </div>  <!-- /.row -->
  </div> <!-- /.container -->
</div> <!-- /.jumbotron -->
```

Comment: it is easy to fix. if i guess correct, set `width:100%` to form and all your div above `class=row` should have some decent width. If you can set up fiddle, i can help you on this further.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/

Comment: your fiddle looks different than your question. where have you used `col-lg-*`?. please set up your exact problem in your fiddle.

Comment: my bad I forgot to fork it: http://jsfiddle.net/LG34D/

Comment: see this. http://jsfiddle.net/LG34D/1/. form already took full width. what is your problem? Do you want input needs to take full width?

Comment: Sorry if my terminology isn't correct. I want the input box to fill the entire form.

Comment: Is this enough? http://jsfiddle.net/LG34D/3/. you failed to load `bootstrap.css` as external source and you should give `form-control` to `input` not to `form`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LG34D/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign class `form-control` to `input` not to `form`.

see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LG34D/4/).